# display hide and show up in javascript jquery mobile?

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, getelementsbyclassname

I have used the following line in my javascript function to show up an element with a class.:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showRates()
{
    //load next page
    alert("hi");
    document.getElementsByClassName('myp').style.display = "block";
}
```

But, display block is not showing up.

Comment: check Bhavik Ambani answer he is right.

Comment: Can you post your HTML part here ?

Comment: use jquery its quite easy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using [jquery-mobile](/questions/tagged/jquery-mobile), why not use it?

```
$('.myp').css('display', 'block');
```

Also, keep in mind that `getElementsByClassName` returns a `NodeList` and doesn't have the `style` property. if you don't want to use jQuery you'd have to iterate over the elements in the list, then apply the `.style.display` changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by the following way

```
$('.myp').hide();
```

And if you want to display the block then

```
$(".myp").show();
```

Comment: `myp` is a tag-name, he's looking for a class selector: `.myp`.